# Continuity of function and finding its domain

Tags: calculus, continuity

I am supposed to find the domain of function given by $f\left ( x \right )=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_{n}\left ( x \right )$ and determine its continuity, where:

$f_{n}\left ( x \right )=\frac{\sin nx}{e^{n^{5}x^{2}}}$.

I did Weierstrass M-test:

$\frac{\sin nx}{e^{n^{5}x^{2}}}\leq \frac{1}{e^{n^{5}}}$, and then I used D'Alembert criterion and I found out that it converge absolutely.

Domain of the function are all real numbers, so can I say, that it is continous on real numbers?

Comment: Try to apply Weierstrass M-test

Comment: @TitoEliatron I edited my answer, can you check it?